# Access VBA - Use a variable to call a subroutine/function in a form's module

Tags: vba, ms-access, subroutine

I have a for loop that stores the name of a subroutine in a string variable, calls that subroutine, and repeats.

```
Public Sub CallByVar_Click()
    Dim i
    Dim st As String
    Dim subName(1)
    subName(0) = "A"
    subName(1) = "B"
        
    For i = 0 To 1
        st = "Sub_" & subName(i)
        Application.Run st
    Next i
End Sub
    
Public Sub Sub_A()
    Debug.Print "run Sub_A"
End Sub
    
Public Sub Sub_B()
    Debug.Print "run Sub_B"
End Sub
```

It works perfectly in a *module*, but when I cut and paste this into a *Form's* code window, it gives the error: Microsoft Access cannot find the procedure 'Sub_A.'

I've tried using functions instead of subs, I've tried using `Call Eval()` instead of `Application.Run`, I can't seem to figure out why it works in a module, but not in a Form. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess `Application.Run` operates in a more global scope and not in the scope of the form. So it can only access the procedures from modules (the forms code is form instance code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *CallByName* for this:

```vb
Public Sub CallByVar_Click()

    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim st          As String
    Dim subName(1)  As String

    subName(0) = "A"
    subName(1) = "B"

    For i = 0 To 1
        st = "Sub_" & subName(i)
        CallByName Me, st, VbMethod
    Next i

End Sub
```